# How to check browser for touchstart support using JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile, unobtrusive-javascript

In an attempt to follow best practices, we're trying to use the proper JavaScript/jQuery events according to what device you are using. For example, we're building a mobile site that has an  tag that will have an onclick or touch event. In the case of an iPhone, we'd like to use the "touchstart" event. We'd like to test if their device supports "touchstart" before we bind that handler to the object. If it doesn't, then we will bind "onclick" instead.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can detect if the event is supported by:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
  //...
}
```

Give a look to this article:

- [Detecting event support without browser sniffing](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/)

The `isEventSupported` function published there, is really good at detecting a wide variety of events, and it's cross-browser.

Comment: I'm sort of tempted to +1 this, but I know that Firefox will return `false` here for the wrong reasons.  Firefox returns false for all events checked in this manner (I know, it's one of those rare situations where Fx sucks).  The article does go into that though, so you get your +1 ;-)

Comment: This only detects if the **browser** supports touch events, it doesn't determine if the **device** supports them. Try this in Chrome on a non–touch device.

Comment: Is this the same as `document.documentElement.hasOwnProperty('ontouchstart')`?

Comment: @Andy E: Looks to be working now. Firefox version 18.0.0.4752 appears to support this after testing with ontouchstart (false) and onclick (true) on my desktop.

Comment: @RobG I ran this in Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m on a non-touch laptop and got `false`, as expected. Am I missing something?

Comment: Be wary of translating `"ontouchstart" in document.documentElement` into coffeescript, it won't work as expected because the `in` operator has different semantics. Rather than figure out how to do this in coffeescript, I just wrapped backticks around it and it worked using the javascript expression.

Comment: is there similar way to detect pointer event api? mainly the safari browser is the one unsupported

Answer (score 12):

Use this code to detect if the device supports touch.

Also work for windows 8 IE10 which uses 'MSPointerDown' event instead of 'touchmove'

```
var supportsTouch = false;
if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
    //iOS & android
    supportsTouch = true;

} else if(window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {

    // Windows
    // To test for touch capable hardware 
    if(navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) {
        supportsTouch = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not simplify it as a one-liner?
``var supportsTouch  = ('ontouchstart' in window || window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) ``

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for ie 11 on Windows 10 on HP laptop (without touchscreen) for me. It wrongly says supportsTouch = true. but when I bind something to "touchstart", it never gets executed. Any way around this?

Comment: This is just wrong. The Pointers API applies to more than just touch devices. It applies to every virtually every input device.

Comment: Modified answer to check for msMaxTouchPoints (tests for touch support)

Answer (score 3):

You could check if `typeof document.body.ontouchstart == "undefined"` to fall back to normal dom events

Answer (score 1):

I made a full demostration that works in every browser with the full source code of the solution of this problem: [Detect touch screen devices in Javascript](http://miloq.blogspot.com/2011/05/detect-touch-devices-javascript.html).

Comment: Your example produces a lot of false positives. There are many browsers that implement the Touch API by default whether or not a touch devices is actually attached to the system.

Comment: @Nilpo Maybe you're right. This post was written more than seven years ago.