# Disable hover effect on mobile. Make it a touch event

Tags: css, mobile, hover, touch, modernizr

I made my website responsive for tablet and smartphone. I used hover for desktop size, but on mobile size there's hover to. I want to change the hover on the mobile device to a touch without using javascript. I heard something about the no-touch modernizr to change hover to touch event?

```
nav{
    margin-left: 2.7em;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    background: #5f6975; 
    border-radius: 0em; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

nav ul {
    background: #333333; 
    padding: 0 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s;
     transition: all 0.5s;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #555555;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a {
    font: 90% helvetica;
    display: block; 
    padding: 1.7em 2em;
    color: #ffffff; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 0.1em solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 1em 2em;
}   
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #292F41;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:40em)
```

What do i need to put here to disable the hover function for mobile and make it a touch?

Comment: Why do you want to disable it...the hover probably won't work anyway? Do you mean`:focus`?

Comment: yes change it to a touch event

Comment: There are no touch events in CSS. So, what effect do you want?

Comment: i want the hover effect changed to a touch by modernizr.

Comment: Modernizr doesn't enable touch events it just tells you when they can be used..then you have to write JS/JQ to deal with it.

Comment: okay what do i need to do to put hover off and still have acces to my submenu without js/jq

Comment: Why is JS/JQ not an option? Anyway, try using `:focus` or `:active` instead of hover for **some** mobile functionality. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063308/touch-css-pseudo-class-or-something-similar