# On mobile, how do I style a hyperlink when it's tapped?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a hyperlink's state when it's tapped on a mobile device. Basically it has to flicker a green color right after being tapped. I've tried all the CSS pseudoclasses for hyperlink states, including:

```
a:active

a:hover

a:focus
```

But on my iPhone, the hyperlink doesn't show the intended style when tapped. Is there a better way through CSS or jQuery to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean while it's being tapped or after it has been tapped? Have you tried [`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)?

Comment: You can check the details from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063308/touch-css-pseudo-class-or-something-similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use a hack along with `:active`

Try adding this event handler to the `<body>` tag:

```
<body ontouchstart="">
```

[Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20220318175636/https://alxgbsn.co.uk/2011/10/17/enable-css-active-pseudo-styles-in-mobile-safari/)