# Chrome 22 confuses tablets and desktops

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I know a lot of JavaScript libraries are depending on "ontouchstart" to detect if it's on tablet or a desktop.

Here's an example of code I'm talking about:

```
    var hasTouch = ("ontouchstart" in window);
```

For now, I had to comment out all the tablet detection code for it to work.

What would be the best way of detecting a tablet vs a desktop?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764020/how-can-i-check-for-real-touch-support-on-a-browser

Comment: The accepted solution is exactly what's broken.

Comment: Do you have a way to reproduce this? `"ontouchstart" in window` returns `false` for me in Chrome 24

Comment: That's interesting. I guess they fixed the issue, which is great!

Comment: For what it's worth, Desktops can have touchscreens too. This looks to me like you're testing for the wrong thing.

Comment: Those events should be disabled when there's no touchscreen present. At least, this used to be the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see if its a mobile platform I've used this

```
var iPadAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
var iPodAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;
var AndroidAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) != null;
var webOSAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) != null;

var isMobile = iPadAgent || iPodAgent || AndroidAgent || webOSAgent;
```

It works pretty well.

Comment: Well ... there's also Blackberry, for example. This is exactly what's wrong with browser sniffing.