# How can we know that the screen in touchable in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html

To develop a responsive application we need to know if the user is using his finger or a mouse  to adapt the behavior of the application. For instance, if the screen is touchable, the buttons will be bigger...

We can listen to `Window.onTouch` events and `Window.onMouse` events to guess if the screen is touchable.

But I would like to know it when the application is loading : before any interaction by the user.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Seems not to be a good idea http://stackoverflow.com/a/12303819/217408. The answer is a bit dated so maybe there are new findings ...

Comment: I remember that somebody proposed a little lib to do that on the Dartisans forum, but I cannot find it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dart:js` and use an approach shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2915912/217408

Add this to your index.html

```dart
<script type="application/javascript">
  function hasTouchSupport() {
    return 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
  }
</script>
```

And call it from Dart like

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' as js;

bool _hasTouchSupport;
bool get hasTouchSupport {
  if(_hasTouchSupport == null) {
    _hasTouchSupport = js.context.callMethod('hasTouchSupport');
  }
  return _hasTouchSupport;
}

void main() {
  print(hasTouchSupport);
}
```

`false` in Dartium/Chrome in Linux
`true` on my Android phone

Comment: Good enough for me, do not really want to add Modernizr

Comment: Just because the screen is touchable doesn't mean the user is controlling it with touch. Laptops with touch screens are becoming more common. It's a difficult issue.

Comment: This is why I added the link to another SO answer below the question. It contains a good explanation for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript) it's not easy to have something that works well for all browser.

If you go with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) you can use:

```dart
 import 'dart:js' as js;

 bool get isTouchDevice => js.context['Modernizr']['touch'];
```