# Chrome 29 window.Touch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

On the desktop version of the chrome 29, the "window.Touch" is no longer set to 'undefined' 
this is a problem because I used it to detect if my app is running on a touch device .

Is there an alternative solution ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement` [source: [How to check browser for touchstart support using JS/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915833/how-to-check-browser-for-touchstart-support-using-js-jquery) ]

```
var isTouchDevice = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
```

or

```
if('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
  //do something with touch stuff
}
```

A lot more detailed answers and more specific solutions here: [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript?lq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `window.Touch.length` is a solution for this problem?