# jQuery event.preventDefault() on touch event does not cancel link

Tags: jquery, touch, preventdefault

So I got a website with a projects index page made of square thumbnails.

On the desktop version when you hover on one project square thumbnail it displays a cover with some text information about the project. And when you click on that cover you go to the project page.

On the mobile/touch version, I got to adapt it otherwise when you tap the square thumb you have no time to see the cover (displayed for a fraction of a second) and it goes directly to the project page.

So here the HTML code of a project square thumbnail inside the portfolio index:

```
<div id="portfolio">
    ... 
    <a href="/projects/project-page" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="/assets/thumbnail-project-name.jpg" alt="Project info"/>
        <div class="text">
            <span class="slogan">Project tagline</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    ... 
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery attempt to try to catch the touch event and do special stuff after...
But for some reason `event.preventDefault()` does not work and my link still continue to fire on touch.

```
$(function onDOMLoaded() {

    var $portfolio = $("#portfolio");

    // TOUCH EVENTS special
    $portfolio.on("touch", ".thumbnail", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // show thumbnail cover and fire the link on second touch only
        // ...

    });

}); // onDOMLoaded
```

Tests made on iPad2/iOS7 and iPhone5/iOS7
jQuery V1.10.2

I am stuggling for days but cannot find a solution myself or in stackover.

Comment: `Touch` is not a jQuery event. Have you tried `on("click" ... `?

Comment: OK silly me. But how do I make the touch device detection to make my special code?

Comment: You use something like jQuery Mobile or a more lightweight library that offers you touch support.

Comment: OK thx : I found the most simple touch detection here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915833/how-to-check-browser-for-touchstart-support-using-js-jquery

Comment: I find it silly that touch support did not make it into regular jQuery, but there is a plugin that adds it: [benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events](https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events) I'm using it and it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will fire the `click` event anyway so you need to put your logic in the `click` event.

Comment: The `click` event adds a [300 ms delay](http://blog.ionic.io/hybrid-apps-and-the-curse-of-the-300ms-delay/) on many mobile devices, so is not ideal.