# Avoid loading of elements on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to build a responsive web site. I want to have a video on the background playing. Of course it will cost too much traffic for the mobile devices. I am using bootstrap and as I know, if I just set the class of the video to hidden-sm and hidden-xs, the video will not be displayed on small devices. But as I know, it will still be loaded, which is going to create some problems for people, who do not have any access to wi-fi. So what is the best solution to prevent this video to be loaded and not to be displayed on mobile devices?

Comment: When you add the class it still loads or you do not know how to add the class?

Comment: i guess check if the userAgent is on mobile then remove the video tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/1059101 this could help you on this.

Comment: Use JS/jQuery is to write the video tag to the DOM based on the screen size and touch availability.

Comment: hey friend check my answer

Answer (score 2):

### Easy and simple method

According to the comments in my answer, I also add this way:

```
if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
    //do stuff
}
```

A mobile device is touch-sensitive so if the touch event exists it has to be mobile.

---

### Javascript

You can detect mobile devices this way with Javascript:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

Now you can check if its a Mobile Device by using this function:

```
if(isMobile.any()) {
   alert("This is a Mobile Device");
}
```

So if the element is for example "#my-element":

```
if(isMobile.any()) {
    //either
    $("#my-element").remove()
    // or 
    $("#my-element").css("display", "none")
}
```

BTW, if the class you add works but you didn't know how to reach this point, you can simply:

```
if(isMobile.any()) {
    //either
    $("#my-element").addClass("hidden-sm") //or hidden-xs, Idk
}
```

---

### CSS

You can do the same with CSS using the following method:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #my-element { display: none; }
}
```

Where 480 px could be the value you consider it is the max. mobile device width, but this is not really precise to determine, since this may vary, and you might find a tablet really big and a laptop whose screen is really small (best approach is JS)

However, there's no single approach that's truly foolproof. The ideal bet would be to mix and match a variety of tricks as needed, to increase the chances of successfully detecting a wider range of handheld devices.

IMO, I'd ask for the user to load the video, and knowing their feedback, either load the video or not. But this may break the ideal look of your page. It's up to you.

---

### Using Regex (from detectmobilebrowsers.com):

Here's a function that uses an insanely long and comprehensive regex which returns a true or false value depending on whether or not the user is browsing with a mobile.

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
}
```

For those wishing to include tablets in this test, you can use the following function:

```
window.mobileAndTabletcheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
}
```

From [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: @Shikkediel Idk any other way to do it, do you?

Comment: I'd go with LShetty's comment myself - screen size and feature detection.

Comment: @Shikkediel I've shown various approaches, not only _browser sniffing_... If they want to help designers, they should add something to check it.

Comment: This should filter out a whole lot : `if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2915912/3168107

Comment: @Shikkediel I've added your comment to my answer, a very clever way btw, but I don't know if it is supported in all browsers.

Comment: Cheers. Like you mentioned, there isn't a bulletproof approach but feature detection is probably the best way to go. Maybe after ruling out the smallest screen sizes. I'd always give the user the opportunity to load the video though and wouldn't assume they can't use a mouse because touch is enabled.

Comment: Only real edge case I could think of is a desktop setup with a touchpad keyboard. But I can't seem to find any good documentation for which events this would generally listen.

Comment: @Shikkediel in Microsoft surface, that's the case

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same issue here.

Eventually, based on the assumption that screens wider than 1200px are definitely
"desktop" screens, i figured it out using AngularJS:
Placed a boolean variable:

```
$rootScope.desktop= $rootScope.body.width() > 1200 ? true : false;
```

Then used ng-if term, which removes an element if the assigned expression is a false value:

```
<video preload autoplay ng-if="desktop">
    <source src="<?php echo base_url('videos/1200bg.mp4') ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```